# Not able to remove last blank line with python or batch script

Tags: python, string, batch-file

My excel file contains:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

My requirement is to concatenate all the above rows into single string like below:

```
ABC or DEF or GHI
```

Below is the code which printed the excel rows into a text file.

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook("abc.xlsx") 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)
with open("data.txt", "w") as dataFile:
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    dataSet = sheet.cell_value(i, 0)
    print(dataSet, file=dataFile)
```

But the data.txt file is printed as:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
<---- this is a blank line ---->
```

So when i am using below code to concatenate the lines:

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as data:
for each_line in data:
    try:
        objList = each_line.replace("\n", " or ")
        print(objList, end='')

    except ValueError:
        pass
```

This is resulting the below output:

```
ABC or DEF or GHI or  --------->This is wrong
```

The required output is :

```
ABC or DEF or GHI  -------------> this is correct
```

Please suggest where i am missing? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken the sample content from your example, where `blank.txt` is the file which has last line as blank. Whereas, `output.txt` file is the file which is new file resulted after removing the last blank line.

1) File with blank line

```
$ cat blank.txt
compponent
BO Applet
Software
Testing

$
```

2) File with blank line removed:

```
$ cat output.txt
compponent
BO Applet
Software
Testing
$
```

**Code which is working:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
with open("blank.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    with open("output.txt", 'w') as w:
        w.write(lines[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

What is exactly the problem here?
Try the following:

```
# Let's assume you have a list named contents with whatever you need to store.
contents[-1].rstrip('\n') # Removing the trailing new line symbol for the last member

with open('cmdOut', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output:
    for line in contents:
        output.write(line)
```